# Android: Failed to measure fs-verity, errno 1 when updating app from code

Tags: android, kotlin, android-intent, viewmodel, auto-update

I'm trying to add an ability to my android-app to update itself via external link to apk with new version.
I'm downloading an apk from external link (I uploaded new build of my app), than I'm using [packageInstaller](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/pm/PackageInstaller) to update an app, and application updates successfully. But after update it crashes with error:

```
VerityUtils pid-594 E  Failed to measure fs-verity, errno 1: /data/app/~~QTV2DULtWFYdJpO7yGn7sg==/com.test.app--JKzM4i9A3BAuvFAm9x9YQ==/base.apk
```

What can be a reason of this? Seems like installation apk-file is corrupted? But how it is possible if update was successfull? (I know this because I see some new text in UI that I added in new version of app)

P.S. app has device owner rights

Here is my code:

```
class UpdateAppViewModel(application: Application): AndroidViewModel(application) {
    fun download() {
        viewModelScope.launch {
            withContext(Dispatchers.IO) {
                val fileUrl = "https://my-path-to-ne-apk-s3.net/test-app"

                val intent = Intent(Intent.ACTION_INSTALL_PACKAGE).apply {
                    data = Uri.parse(fileUrl)
                    flags = Intent.FLAG_GRANT_READ_URI_PERMISSION or Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK
                }
                Log.d("UPD", "START DOWNLOAD")

                val packageInstaller = getApplication<Application>().packageManager.packageInstaller
                val sessionParams = PackageInstaller.SessionParams(PackageInstaller.SessionParams.MODE_FULL_INSTALL)
                val sessionId = packageInstaller.createSession(sessionParams)
                val session = packageInstaller.openSession(sessionId)

                val inputStream = URL(fileUrl).openStream()
                val outputStream = session.openWrite("test-app.apk", 0, -1)
                inputStream.copyTo(outputStream)
                session.fsync(outputStream)
                inputStream.close()
                outputStream.close()
                Log.d("UPD", "FINISH DOWNLOAD")

                val pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(getApplication<Application>().applicationContext, 0, intent, 0)
                Log.d("UPD", "BEFORE COMMIT!")
                session.commit(pendingIntent.intentSender)
                Log.d("UPD", "AFTER COMMIT!")
                session.close()
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Basicly, it seems like a normal behavior. All I did to improve user experience - added broadcast reciever with intent to launch main activity after app has been updated. So, for user i looks like app has been updated and restarted. Here is the code:

```
class PackageInstallerStatusReceiver : BroadcastReceiver() {
    override fun onReceive(context: Context?, intent: Intent?) {
        Log.d("UPD!", "APP HAS BEEN UPDATED!")

        if (context == null) {
            Log.d("ERR!", "Context should not be null")
            return
        }

        val stIntent = Intent(context, MainActivity::class.java)
        startActivity(context, stIntent, null)
        return
    }
}
```

Also, I noticed that in erlier Android versions the behavior is not the same - app crashes, but there is no error form VerityUtils. Looks like some security mechanism in Android 13.